# Multiple where queries on same column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database of customers and would like to run a query to display how many customers have an active account on a month by month basis.

I already have the following to count how many customers have an expiry date for each month, but can anybody suggest a way to then count those with an expirydate >= now for each month?

```
<?php 
$query = "select count(cid) as num_rows from customers WHERE expirydate LIKE '%-12-%'";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ); 
$total = $row->num_rows; 
echo "December: " .$total; 
?>
```

Comment: Exactly as you wrote. There is an SQL function for it, called `NOW()`

Comment: A little reading of mysql's time and date functions might help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Side note: That LIKE clause is a rather round about way of doing `WHERE MONTH(expirydate) = 12`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
mysql_query( "select count(cid) as num_rows from customers WHERE expirydate >= curdate()" );
```

Try to avoid **mysql**_* functions due to they are **depricated**.Instead use **mysqli**_* functions or **PDO** statements

Comment: But that just counts all customers with an expiry date that is current - is there no way to group it by month?

Ie.

January - 30 active customers etc?

Answer (score 0):

This query show you how much customers has expirydate after now. Correct your date format in STR_TO_DATE function for your case. [MySQL STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `num_rows`, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`expirydate`,'%Y-%m-%d')) as `month`
FROM `customers`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`expirydate`,'%Y-%m-%d') > NOW()
GROUP BY `month`
```

Also try to use timestamp field type in your tables instead of varchar or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following will tell you have many customers have an expirydate per month for records on or after today.

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(expirydate) month, COUNT(cid) as count 
FROM 
    customers 
WHERE 
    DATE(expirydate) >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY MONTH(expirydate)
```

Do note though that as this groups only by month, records spanning multiple years may be misleading (3 July 2013 and 7 Jul 2014 would both count as July, for example).

You should look into the [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and [group by/aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for more information.

Comment: I have tried this but it just returns a blank result. The expiry date column is set to date, with the format yyyy-mm-dd